# Telebot Python - how to send photos group

Tags: python, telebot

I'm trying to send photos from disk with media group and pyTelegramBotAPI (latest version 4.10.0)

```
import telebot
from telegram import InputMediaPhoto
from telegram.constants import ParseMode
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_KEY)
all_photos = []
IMAGE_FILE_PATH = "images/image.jpg"
current_image_file = open(IMAGE_FILE_PATH, 'rb')
all_photos.append(InputMediaPhoto(
           media = current_image_file,
           parse_mode = ParseMode.HTML,
           caption = "Sample <b>Text</b>"
))
all_photos.append(InputMediaPhoto(
           media = current_image_file,
           parse_mode = ParseMode.HTML,
           caption = "Sample <b>Text</b>"
))
bot.send_media_group(CHAT_ID, all_photos)
```

That code return error:
*** telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: there are no messages to send

How it can be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from telegram import InputMediaPhoto
```

`InputMediaPhoto` needs to be imported from `telebot.types`

---

Here an example based on your code:

```py
import telebot
from telebot.types import InputMediaPhoto

CHAT_ID=123456
API_KEY='85916......'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_KEY)

all_photos = []

for pic in [ "./photo1.png", "./photo2.png" ]:

    current_image_file = open(pic, 'rb')
    mediaPhoto = InputMediaPhoto(current_image_file, "Sample <b>Text</b>")

    all_photos.append(mediaPhoto)

bot.send_media_group(CHAT_ID, all_photos)
```

Which results in this message send by the Bot:
[image]